# Beep through the soundcard

Tags: c#, audio, beep

I'm using beep (import from kernel) in C# to send tones through the headphone jack to another device that interprets them.

The problem is on some computers the beep occurs, but nothing is output to the hp jack. I think it's because it is using the internal speaker. How can I send it through the soundcard?

Comment: Actually it's beep function from kernel.dll

Comment: That's the same thing, pinvoked by Console.Beep().

Comment: in the original question, you mentioned it as System.Beep, hence the desire to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older machines might still have a speaker, Console.Beep() will drive the speaker, not the soundcard.  Not much you can do about it since this is a driver detail, but ask at superuser.com.  This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx) has details about how this came about.

Check out the [NAudio library](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) for a way to generate sound through the sound card.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are using 64-bit Windows. It is not supported on 64 bit. Frankly, don't use this API.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a short audio clip, perhaps a .wav or .mp3 file, and play that.  It will output through the user's chosen audio output device, which is almost certain to be their soundcard.